# Knockoutjs is calling a REST API Post twice

Tags: asp.net-mvc, api, rest, knockout.js

I am working on an ASP.NET MVC application using knockoutjs for MVVM. I when trying to make a Post to an ASP.NET Core API, the request from knockout seems to be posting 2 times. Below is the knockoutjs viewModel

```
var viewModel = function () {
    var self = this;
    self.Surname = ko.observable("").extend({ required: { message: 'Please supply your surname' } });
    self.Firstname = ko.observable("").extend({ required: { message: 'Please supply your firstname' } });
    self.Middlename = ko.observable("");
    self.Title = ko.observable().extend({ required: true });
     
    self.save = function () {
       
            $.ajax({
                contentType: 'application/json',
                url: 'https://localhost:44337/api/Student/SaveStudent',
                type: 'post',
                data: ko.toJSON(self),
                dataType: "json",
                processData:false;
                success: function (data) {
                    alert(data);
                    
                },
                error: function (err) {
                    alert(err.status + " : " + err.statusText);
                    self.Kill(false);
                }
                
            });
        }

    }
    
}
ko.applyBindings(new viewModel());

[HttpPost]
        public IActionResult SaveStudent(StudentDTO student)
        {
            var st = _studentService.SaveStudent(student);
             
            return Ok(st);
        }
```

On save, the API is hit twice, first hit returns a status 204 and the second says:"request fail".
But If i call same API using postman it executes successfully without any error

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that this part is causing your issue: data: ko.toJSON(self). Usual pattern in knockouts vm architecture is to extract all data that is to be sent to the server inside of a separate model and use an instance of that model throughout your pageVm function.

```
// separate model
function Person(){
    var self = this;
    self.Surname = ko.observable("").extend({ required: { message: 'Please supply your surname' } });
    self.Firstname = ko.observable("").extend({ required: { message: 'Please supply your firstname' } });
    self.Middlename = ko.observable("");
    self.Title = ko.observable().extend({ required: true });
}

// inside of pageVM create an instance
var data = new Person()

//inside of your ajax call
data: ko.toJSON(data),
```